# Efficient data structure to store a string, an integer and a real number for each record

Tags: r, data-structures, dataframe

I would like to build a structure which, for each record, stores a string, an index and a numeric value. I would like to be able to access the numeric value by querying the data structure with either the index or the string. Also, the data structure is small (on the order of 30 records) but it must be accessed and modified many times (possibly even a million times). Normally I would just use a data frame, but given the efficiency requirements, do you think there would be a better (faster) way? Judging by the syntax, I have the impression that `my_struct` needs to be accessed two times for each operation (read or write): maybe it's not a big deal, but I wonder if expert R coders, when efficiency is a constraint, would use this code or something different.

```
# define data structure
my_struct <- data.frame(index = c(3:14,24), variable = c("Pin", "Pout", "Tout", "D", "L", "mu", "R","K","c","omega","alpha","beta","gamma"), value = runif(13), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# examples of read/write statements 
my_struct$value[my_struct$variable == "Pin"]
my_struct$value[my_struct$index %in% c(3:14)]
my_struct$value[my_struct$index %in% c(3,5)] <- rnorm(2)
```

Comment: You probably want `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` there if you really want a string.

Comment: Anyways, data.table supports efficient indexing on multiple indices with binary search and nice syntax. See http://r-datatable.com One thing to note, though: it does not support insertion or deletion of rows/records.

Comment: @Frank got it, thanks for the tip. I definitely want a real string, so I corrected my code accordingly.

Comment: @Frank I'm a bit afraid of using `data.table`, because last time I tried I found the syntax not very intuitive, and also I would lose the possibility of using the `tidyverse` packages. Anyway, if no other suggestions arrive, I guess I'll have to go for `data.table`.

Comment: Btw, if it is accessed and modified "possibly even a million times" in a short period of time, I think you run into classical database issues surrounding concurrency... in which case you should probably just use a DBMS or consult an expert in those.

Comment: @Frank, it's an iterative process (Bayesian inference). In practice I need to do something like this: `for i in seq(1,10^6) {write an input file, launch an executable, read the output, decide which input to use next}`. So I don't think I'll run into concurrency issues, because it's mostly a sequential process. No idea what a DBMS is :)

Comment: Ah ok, thought maybe you meant you'd be posting some table online for thousands of people to access and modify or something. Personally, I just use a named vector for this (passing it to `optim`). If necessary, the mapping from names to a numeric `index` can be stored separately, to be used as (very rarely) needed.

Comment: @Frank I think I need the numeric `index`, actually. The reason is hard to explain in a comment - I'll post another question where it should be evident, and put the link to the question here below.

Comment: @Frank the question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373726/reading-a-template-file-and-writing-it-to-disk-after-some-modifications. You can see there why `index` is needed: basically, for each parameter it tells me the line number in a text file where I have to write the parameter. The text file is the input file of an executable code, which computes the objective function for my optimization. So for each optimization iteration I need to modify the input file and run the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data.table package supports indices and has nice syntax for read and write:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(index = c(3:14,24), variable = c("Pin", "Pout", "Tout", "D", "L", "mu", "R","K","c","omega","alpha","beta","gamma"), value = runif(13))

setindex(dat, index)
setindex(dat, variable)

# read
dat[ index %in% 3:4, value ]

# write
dat[ index %in% 3:4, value := 2:3 ]
```

To see how the index works, add `verbose = TRUE`, like `dat[ index %in% 3:4, value := 2:3, verbose = TRUE ]` and read the [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). (Indices are covered in the fourth one.)

Benchmark for OP's example

```
library(microbenchmark)
datDF = data.frame(dat)

n_idx  = 2L
idxcol = "variable"
idx    = sample(dat[[idxcol]], n_idx)
v      = rnorm(length(idx))
e      = substitute(idxcol %in% idx, list(idxcol = as.name(idxcol)))
microbenchmark(
  DT  = dat[eval(e), value := v ],
  DF  = datDF$value[ datDF[[idxcol]] %in% idx ] <- v
)

# Unit: microseconds
#  expr     min      lq      mean  median       uq      max neval
#    DT 449.694 473.136 487.17583 481.042 487.0065 1049.193   100
#    DF  27.742  30.239  44.21525  36.065  38.4225  854.723   100
```

So it's actually slower. I'd still go with it for the (in my opinion) nicer syntax. Note that dplyr has no syntax for updating a subset of rows.

With a large table, you'd see the benchmark reversed:

```
dat = data.table(variable = do.call(paste0, CJ(LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS)))
dat[, index := .I ]
dat[, value := rnorm(.N) ]
setindex(dat, index)
setindex(dat, variable)

datDF = data.frame(dat)

n_idx  = 2L
idxcol = "variable"
idx    = sample(dat[[idxcol]], n_idx)
v      = rnorm(length(idx))
e      = substitute(idxcol %in% idx, list(idxcol = as.name(idxcol)))
microbenchmark(
  DT = dat[eval(e), value := v ],
  DF = datDF$value[ datDF[[idxcol]] %in% idx ] <- v
)

# Unit: microseconds
#  expr       min         lq       mean    median        uq       max neval
#    DT   471.887   492.5545   701.7914   757.766   817.827  1647.582   100
#    DF 17387.134 17729.3280 23750.6721 22629.490 25912.309 83057.928   100
```

*Note*: The DF way can also be written `datDF$value[ match(idx, datDF[[idxcol]]) ] <- v`, but I'm seeing about the same timing.