# reading a template file and writing it to disk after some modifications

Tags: r, file-io

I need to read a template file `test.txt`, modify the contents and then write to disk a modified copy with name `` foo`i`.in `` (`i` is an iteration number). Since I need to perform this operation a large number of times (a million times wouldn't be uncommon), efficient solutions would be preferred. The template file is like this:

```
1 
bar.out 
       70.000000000000000 
        2.000000000000000 
       14.850000000000000 
     8000.000000000000000 
      120.000000000000000 
       60.000000000000000 
        0.197500000000000 
        0.197500000000000 
        2.310000000000000 
        0.200000000000000 
        0.000000000000000 
        1.000000000000000 
        0.001187700000000 
       22.000000000000000 
        1.400000000000000 
        1.000000000000000 
        0.010000000000000 
100 
        0.058600000000000 
       -0.217000000000000 
        0.078500000000000 
       -0.110100000000000 
30 
      500.000000000000000 
T
```

I don't need to modify all lines, just some of them. Specifically, I need to modify `bar.out` to `` bar`i`.out `` where `i` is an iteration index. I also need to modify some numeric lines with the following values:

```
parameters <- data.frame(index = c(1:10, 13:16, 21:22), variable = c("P1", 
                      "P2", "T1", "s", "D", "L", "C1", "C2", "VA", 
                      "pw", "m", "mw", "Cp", "Z", "ff_N", "ff_M"),
                      value = c(65, 4, 16.85, 7900, 110, 60, 0.1975, .1875, 2.31,
                                 0.2, 0.0011877, 22.0, 1.4, 1.0, 0.0785, -0.1101))
```

All the other lines must remain the same, including the last line `T`. Thus, assuming I'm at the first iteration, **the expected output** is a text file named `foo1.in` having the content (the exact number format is not important, as long as all the significant digits in `parameters$value` are included in `foo1.in`):

```
1 
bar1.out 
       65.000000000000000 
        4.000000000000000
       16.850000000000000 
     7900.000000000000000 
      110.000000000000000 
       60.000000000000000 
        0.197500000000000 
        0.187500000000000 
        2.310000000000000 
        0.200000000000000 
        0.000000000000000 
        1.000000000000000 
        0.001187700000000 
       22.000000000000000 
        1.400000000000000 
        1.000000000000000 
        0.010000000000000 
100 
        0.058600000000000 
       -0.217000000000000 
        0.078500000000000 
       -0.110100000000000 
30 
      500.000000000000000 
T
```

Modifying `foo.in` and `bar.out` is easy:

```
template  <- "test.txt"
infile    <- "foo.in"
string1 <- "bar.out"
iteration <- 1

# build string1
elements <- strsplit(string1, "\\.")[[1]]
elements[1] <- paste0(elements[1], iteration)
string1 <- paste(elements, collapse = ".")

# build infile name
elements <- strsplit(infile, "\\.")[[1]]
elements[1] <- paste0(elements[1], iteration)
infile<- paste(elements, collapse = ".")
```

Now, I would like to read the template file and modify only the intended lines. The first problem I face is that `read.table` only outputs a data frame. Since my template file contains numbers and strings in the same column, if I read all the file with `read.table` I would obtain a character column (I guess). I circumvent the problem by reading only the numeric values I'm interested in:

```
    # read template file   
    temp <- read.table(template, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip = 2, nrows = 23)$V1
    lines_to_read <- temp[length(temp)]

    # modify numerical parameter values
    temp[parameters$index] <- parameters$value
```

However, now I don't know how to write `foo1.in`. If I use `write.table`, I can only write matrices or dataframes to disk, so I can't write a file which contains numbers and strings in the same column. How can I solve this?

EDIT I provide a bit of background on this problem, to explain why I need to write this file so many times. So, the idea is to perform Bayesian inference for the calibration parameters of a computer code (an executable). The basic idea is simple: you have a black box (commercial) computer code,  which simulates a physical problem, for example a FEM code. Let's call this code Joe. Given an input file, Joe outputs a prediction for the response of a physical system. Now, I also have actual experimental measurements for the response of this system. I would like to find values of Joe's inputs such that the difference between Joe's outputs and the real measurements is minimized (actually things are quite different, but this is just to give an idea). In practice, this means that I need to run Joe many times with different input files, and iteratively find the input values which reduce the "discrepancy" between Joe's prediction and experimental results. In short:

1. I need to generate many input (text) files
2. I don't know in advance the contents of the input files. The numerical parameters are modified during the optimization in an iterative way.
3. I also need to read Joe's output for each input. This is actually another problem and I'll probably write a specific question on this point.

So, while Joe is a commercial code for which I only have the executable (no source), the Bayesian inference is performed in R, because R (and, for what it matters, Python) have excellent tools to perform this kind of study.

Comment: Reading and writing to a plain text file on disk at each iteration will be inefficient compared storing things in an R object. Your estimate vector is small, so I don't think putting it on disk would be justified by concerns about limited RAM. You're using some non-R thing to do optimization but handling the iteration part in R?

Comment: @Frank thanks for the interest. It's a bit complicated: I will edit the question to provide background, hope it gets more clear.

Comment: Is the `parameters` variable identical for all input files, or does it change based on something in the input file (or elsewhere)?

Comment: @r2evans `parameters$value` changes for each input file (each iteration of the Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) algorithm). The values are iteratively modified by the MCMC, trying to reduce the negative log likelihood of the difference between Joe's predictions and experiments.

Comment: Okay, so you read in `test.txt` *once* (per run), and then "*n* times" you (1) calculate a new set of `parameters`, (2) nutate the data per these `parameters`, (3) change `bar.out` to `bar___.out` (based on an iterator), and then write to a numbered file. Is that about it? It seems the left/right alignment and number of digits is strictly meaningful, is that right? Do the left-aligned labels change or change location?

Comment: @r2evans sorry for the late reply, but apparently the site didn't show me any notice that you added a new comment. Anyway: right now I read `test.txt` every time, but you just made me realize that's silly :D, so yes, I'll read `test.txt` once for run and then `n` times etc. etc. Concerning the left/right alignement and the number of digits: I've made a few random checks and it looks like it's not meaningful. As long as it's one record per line, the bloody code seems to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably easiest solved using a template language, such as [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/), which is implemented in R in the [whisker](https://github.com/edwindj/whisker) package.

Below is an example showing how this can be done in your case. As an example, I only implemented the first three variables and the `bar1.out`. Implementing the remaining variables should be straightforward.

```
library(whisker)


# You could also read the template in using readLines
# template <- readLines("template.txt")
# but to keep example selfsufficient, I included it in the code
template <- "1 
bar{{run}}.out 
      {{P1}}
      {{P2}}
      {{T1}}
     8000.000000000000000 
      120.000000000000000 
       60.000000000000000 
        0.197500000000000 
        0.197500000000000 
        2.310000000000000 
        0.200000000000000 
        0.000000000000000 
        1.000000000000000 
        0.001187700000000 
       22.000000000000000 
        1.400000000000000 
        1.000000000000000 
        0.010000000000000 
100 
        0.058600000000000 
       -0.217000000000000 
        0.078500000000000 
       -0.110100000000000 
30 
      500.000000000000000 
T"


# Store parameters in a list
parameters <- list(
  run = 1, 
  P1 = 65,
  P2 = 4,
  T1 = 16.85)

for (i in seq_len(10)) {
  # New set of parameters
  parameters$run <- i
  parameters$P1  <- sample(1:100, 1)

  # Generate new script by rendering the template using paramers
  current_script <- whisker.render(template, parameters)
  writeLines(current_script, paste0("foo", i, ".in"))

  # Run script
  # system(...)
}
```

What mustache does (in this case; more complex templating is possible; e.g. conditional elements) is replace all `{{<variable>}}` with the corresponding value in the `parameters` list.

Comment: this looks very simple! For the reasons explained in my comments to @r2evans, I'd like not to hard-code the string `"bar.out"`. I think I could adapt your example by just adding two variables, `{{outfile_prefix}}` and `{{outfile_suffix}}`. Right?

Comment: @DeltaIV You are right, or you could have one field `{{outfile}}` and construct the filename in R.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need custom read/write functions; not ideal, but when you have a hybrid column-like-thing, you already diverge from "neat data" (whether or not it is tidy).

Three functions that simplify what I believe you need:

```
read_myfile <- function(x) {
  # mostly during dev
  if (file.exists(x)) x <- readLines(x)
  if (length(x) == 1) x <- strsplit(rawfile, "\n")[[1]]
  # find all left-aligned NAMED rows
  hdrs <- grep("[A-Za-z]", x)
  hdrs <- c(1, hdrs) # ensure the first "1" is preserved
  dat <- mapply(function(a,b,x) if (b >= a) as.numeric(x[seq(a, b)]),
                hdrs + 1, c(hdrs[-1] - 1, length(x)), list(x),
                SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  names(dat) <- trimws(x[hdrs])
  dat
}

mod_myfile <- function(x, i, params) {
  # sanity checks
  stopifnot(
    is.list(x),
    is.numeric(i),
    is.data.frame(params),
    all(c("index", "value") %in% colnames(params))
  )
  isbarout <- which(names(x) == "bar.out")
  stopifnot(
    length(isbarout) == 1
  )
  x$bar.out[ params$index ] <- params$value
  names(x)[isbarout] <- sprintf("bar%i.out", i)
  x
}

write_myfile <- function(x, ...) {
  newdat <- unlist(unname(
    mapply(function(hdr, dat) c(hdr, sprintf("%25.15f ", dat)),
           names(x), x, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
  ))
  writeLines(newdat, ...)
}
```

The use is straight-forward. I'll start with a single character string to emulate the input template (the read function works equally well with a character string as it does with a file name):

```
rawfile <- "1 
bar.out 
       70.000000000000000 
        2.000000000000000 
       14.850000000000000 
     8000.000000000000000 
      120.000000000000000 
       60.000000000000000 
        0.197500000000000 
        0.197500000000000 
        2.310000000000000 
        0.200000000000000 
        0.000000000000000 
        1.000000000000000 
        0.001187700000000 
       22.000000000000000 
        1.400000000000000 
        1.000000000000000 
        0.010000000000000 
100 
        0.058600000000000 
       -0.217000000000000 
        0.078500000000000 
       -0.110100000000000 
30 
      500.000000000000000 
T 
"
```

To start, just read the data:

```
dat <- read_myfile(rawfile)
# dat <- read_myfile("file.in")
str(dat)
# List of 3
#  $ 1      : NULL
#  $ bar.out: num [1:24] 70 2 14.8 8000 120 ...
#  $ T      : NULL
```

You will somehow determine how the parameters *should* be changed. I'll use your previous data:

```
parameters <- data.frame(
  index = c(1:10, 13:16, 21:22),
  variable = c("P1", "P2", "T1", "s", "D", "L", "C1", "C2",
               "VA", "pw", "m", "mw", "Cp", "Z", "ff_N", "ff_M"),
  value = c(65, 4, 16.85, 7900, 110, 60, 0.1975, .1875, 2.31,
            0.2, 0.0011877, 22.0, 1.4, 1.0, 0.0785, -0.1101)
)
```

The first parameter is the output from `read_myfile`; the second is the iterator you want to augment `bar.out`; the third is this `parameters` data.frame:

```
newdat <- mod_myfile(dat, 32, parameters)
str(newdat)
# List of 3
#  $ 1        : NULL
#  $ bar32.out: num [1:24] 65 4 16.9 7900 110 ...
#  $ T        : NULL
```

And now write it out.

```
write_myfile(newdat, sprintf("foo%d.in", 32))
```

I don't know how @GiovanniRighi's performance will compare when run in a single R session, but 1000 of these files takes less than 7 seconds on my computer.

Comment: wow! that's way more advanced than whatever I could come out with :) I'm having some difficulties in understanding your code, though. In `read_myfile`: a) what's the purpose of `if (length(x) == 1)...`? b) can you explain what `mapply` is doing? In `mod_myfile ` I would like `"bar.out"` not to be hard-coded. I can just add it as a dummy argument, right? i.e.,  `mod_myfile <- function(x, i, params, output_filename) {...`. In `write_myfile`: I think the goal of `mapply` is to enforce a fixed format on all parameters, right?

Comment: The first two lines of code in `read_myfile` are solely to facilitate accepting a raw string as well as a filename; it's helpful in testing, but unused in production. Feel free to remove the first two lines (both `if`) from `read`. For `mod`: this func does not output the file, it just modifies the structure. The change to `bar%d.out` impacts the second line of the file, not the filename. I was following your "expected output". The `mapply` lines are to allow re-merging what immutables I "saved" as names in the list (e.g., `1`, `bar.out`, and `T`).

Comment: Also, there is no reason you *cannot* combine `mod_` and `write_myfile` into a single function; heck, depending on how you determine the new parameters, you could even combine all three into a single function. I broke them apart for clarity and demonstration. Having said that, for maintenance and readability, it's often better (in the long) to keep functions single-purpose and orthogonal: do one (small) thing, do it well, and do nothing else.

Comment: right, the name of the input file is `foo%d.in`. But the second line of the input file (`bar%d.out`) is the **output** filename: in other words, the input file for Joe (`foo%d.in`) stores on line 2 the name that Joe will use for its **output file**. That's why I was suggesting to use a variable `output_filename` to store the string `"bar.out"`.

Comment: you are right, it's probably better to keep the three functions separate.

Comment: I agree that the [`whisker`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/whisker/index.html) solution is strong and robust. I had assumed that the template file was being created by something else, since you needed to keep certain parameters untouched. I suggest you don't technically need a template file at all. (Frankly, `sprintf` could work almost as well as the `whiskey` solution, at the cost of explicit readability.)

Comment: both your solutions were great and I struggled a lot to choose among them (that's why I didn't choose until today). In the end I went the `whisker` way, thus I chose that answer - but I found your answer also very useful, and I'm sure other users will find your solution more useful.  In the end, I liked both suggestions but I can only choose one answer, sorry!

Comment: I'm not complaining! :-)  The solution depends on the interpretation of the constraints, and I made an assumption that did not pan out: that the template file is dynamically generated externally (as in "something else started a random process, I then nutate it slightly"). I tend to prefer elegant and readable solutions, and in this case, `whisker` is that solution.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of tricks should help. Let's follow a minimum working example that - I think - has all the features of your problem. Here are the contents of the file I'm modifying, tmp.txt:

```
1
bar.out
21
31
T
```

Typically we work with *lists* rather than vectors when R has heterogeneous data. But here it seems to me easier to work with a character vector. Read the file from a text connection into a character vector:

```
a <- readLines("tmp.txt")
```

Since you have the replacement values, replace them just like you would the strings. Since it looks like you have the replacement of the strings under control, let's change those numbers. We'll want to convert the numeric vector you have to a character vector.

```
value <- c(21, 31)
value <- as.character(value)
a[3:4] <- value
```

Now write to replace the old file:

```
writeLines(a, "tmp.txt")
```

---

Now Frank's comment is relevant because file I/O will be a serious bottleneck here. It would be much faster to do all of this in RAM.

```
 time for i in {1..1000}; do ./run.R; done

 real   0m44.988s
 user   0m33.270s
 sys    0m5.170s
```

Time seemed to increase linearly, so I'd expected a million iterations to take around 16 hours. Most of that time is file reading and writing. You can attempt to speed that up, but I don't think you'll be able to increase it much unless you can get your MCMC binary to spit out Rdata binaries (or feather files).

Comment: How does it perform if you do the looping within R? Seems to me you are confounding R startup in that time estimate.

Comment: I think @r2evans is right - you're launching an R script for each iteration. I'm not sure, because I don't know enough about R inner workings, but if I just put that code inside a function and called the function at each iteration, maybe it would be faster.